# IBM MQ Pubsub message too large

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a Normal IBM MQ developer edition 924 installed on a ubuntu virtual machine. And have cpp code files for Publisher and Subscriber model. I created a topic and started sending messages on the topic.

> The issue happens when I send a larger message on the topic, the error code of 2031(MQRC_MSG_TOO_BIG_FOR_Q_MGR) is outputted. (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=arc-2031-07ef-rc2031-mqrc-msg-too-big-q-mgr)

I changed the maxmsgl value for the Queue manager and the SVR channel as well. I ran the following commands for this:

```
runmqsc QM1
ALTER QMGR MAXMSGL(104857600)
ALTER CHANNEL(SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) maxmsgl(104857600)
```

But still the error persists, could someone reflect on what needs to be done regarding this error code. And also as message segmentation is not allowed on pubsub what is the maximum limit of message size it can handle.

Comment: The queue the messages land on also needs to have maxmsgl increased.   If if it is a SYSTEM* queue then updated the model queue.

Comment: @JoshMc how can I tell if it's a system queue? and what is the default name for it? I tried changing the maxmsgl for DEV.QUEUE.1 but didn't help.

Comment: Look at the DEST of the SUB. Default name for managed subscriptions start with SYSTEM.MANAGED.

Comment: @JoshMc it's not a managed subscription, I just send the message to the topic and get the message with the subscriber application, I get the message with the normal MQGET function , the subscription settings are not changed in the queue manager level.

Comment: @JoshMc just one more detail. I am not following server and client installations differently. I have one server installation where the queue manager is hosted and has a topic which is connected to the both the Publisher and subscriber applications. and All of this is on a single ubuntu VM.

Comment: If it's not a managed subscription then you must be telling it which queue to use. Regardless of whether it is managed or not, there will be a queue where the messages are sent. As @JoshMc said in his first comment you need to set the MAXMSGL on the queue, possible QMODEL, being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a topic for publish/subscribe, the messages sent to subscribers are still put onto a queue for safe storage until they are consumed by the subscribing/getting application. These queues must also have MAXMSGL set appropriately.

If you do not know which queue to adjust, follow these steps:-

1. Run the subscriber application - assuming that it will wait around for a while
2. Issue the following MQSC command (e.g. using `runmqsc`):-

```
DISPLAY SUB(*) DEST DESTCLAS TOPICSTR DURABLE
```

3. The name shown in the `DEST` field in the output is the queue your subscription is using. If it's name starts with `SYSTEM.MANAGED` and it also shows `DESTCLAS(MANAGED)` then your subscription is a managed subscription. You say that your subscription is not managed, but if you don't know which queue is in use by that subscriber then it is most likely that it IS managed, since that means you don't have to worry about the queue.
4. A managed subscription queue is built from a MODEL queue referenced on the topic. If you are unsure which MODEL queue would be used, issue the following command using the `TOPICSTR` value from the output of the above command.

```
DISPLAY TPSTATUS('topic-str-value') MNDURMDL MDURMDL
```

5. If the output from the `DISPLAY SUB` command earlier showed that your subscription was `DURABLE(YES)` then the MODEL queue in use is the one shown in the field `MDURMDL` (Managed DURable MoDeL). If it showed `DURABLE(NO)` then the MODEL queue in use is the one shown in the field `MNDURMDL` (Managed Non-DURable MoDeL).
6. Using the name determined in step 4 if it is not managed, or in step 5 if it is managed, issue the following MQSC command:-

```
ALTER QLOCAL('q-name-from-step-4') MAXMSGL(104857600)
or
ALTER QMODEL('q-name-from-step-5') MAXMSGL(104857600)
```

Now re-make your subscription (so that it deletes the previous temporary queue it created and makes a new one from the model) and re-run your publisher application.